# PHP: Check if a variable is an instance of a certain class

Tags: php

Every time I get a variable through $_GET I want to verify that it is indeed an object of the User class.

So:

```
if (isUser($_GET['valid_user']))
{
...
}
```

is there a built in function to use instead of this so called "isUser"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can verify any variable for a certain class:

```
if ($my_var instanceof classname)
```

however, in your case that will never work, as $_GET["valid_user"] comes from the request and is never going to be an object.

isUser() is probably a custom function from a user management library that authenticates the current session. You need to take a look how that works if you want to replace it.

Comment: For others: note that `classname` is not a string - it is the class identifier (that may be imported with the `use` keyword).

Answer (score 6):

There is a function in the PHP language, which might help you:

```
bool is_a ( object $object , string $class_name )
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php): *Checks if the object is of this class or has this class as one of its parents*

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
if (is_object($_GET['valid_user']))
{
     // more code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is_object to check if it is a object and link below explains how to check which class

http://hr.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinstance.php

Answer (score 0):

$_GET[] variables are more constants than variables, they are read only .. but happen to be accessed like you would any other `$variable`.

In your example:

```
if (isUser($_GET['valid_user']))
{
...
}
```

I would *hope* that it would read:

```
if (isUser($some_sanatized_variable))
```

.. unless isUser() is what's doing that. 'Variables' that PHP sets don't belong to any class, which illustrates my concern that isUser() may not adequately know what its dealing with.